# Setting Map Values to JSP parameters

Tags: jsp, url-parameters

I basically want to set my JSP parameters with `Map` values.

I am trying to do the following thing in my JSP:

```
<input type="hidden" name="reportSubCategories" value="<%= reportsForm.getReportSubCategories()%>" />
```

I know that a parameter can only be set with a `String` type variable and hence, the above code doesn't work.But still, is there any workaround?

Comment: Here where you have used your Map?

Comment: I am getting a return of the type Map from reportsForm.getReportSubCategories(), with which I want to set the parameter.

Comment: That's not possible. If you want you can iterate through your map and create hidden input for each entry .

Comment: Are you trying to create a single hidden input field for all of the values in your map? Or one input per value? If it's one per value JSTL foreach loop would solve your problem.

Comment: Yes !! But it's one for the entire Map value.

Comment: Can you add an example of you Map?

Comment: It's nothing different. Just a normal Map with Report Sub Categories that apply to the current report.

Comment: Assume it to be the most basic Map.